# Python - Simple thread won't stop

Tags: python, multithreading

I'm having a problem with a python script using threads. I could mimic the problem with the following code:

```
from threading import Thread

def func1():
    while True:
        print 'Function 1'

def main():
    t = Thread(target = func1)

    t.start()

    for i in xrange(100000):
        print 'Main'

    t.stop()

    print 'End'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The problem is when I interrupt the script with ***Ctrl + C*** or when it reaches its end, the thread running `func1()` won't stop.

I can only interrupt the execution if open the terminal and `killall python`.

This is the first time I'm working with threads in Python. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Ctrl+C does not stop threads on python2. I can only recommend making `t` a daemon thread using `Thread(target=func1, daemon=True)`

Comment: It worked. I had to make it a daemon before the start  `t.dameon = True` and then `t.start()`. Thanks @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ!

Comment: I was under the impression that you can initialise it during the constructor call, but that works too.

Comment: Just note you should only use daemon if you don't care if the thread abruptly stops; not a good idea when working with files etc.

Answer (score 1):

My approach (perhaps not the best, but it works) is:

1. Have a variable that the thread checks to see if it should stop.
2. Catch the ctrl-c in your main function.
3. When caught, main function sets the variable that indicates the thread should stop.
4. Main function calls `join()` on the thread to wait for it to finish.
5. Thread checks the variable, sees it is set, and returns (stops).
6. The `join()` returns and you allow your main function to exit.